# I want this script to work when page load and also when resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

The site is responsive

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $('#drop_ul').css('width', $('#container').width());
    $('#drop_ul').css('left', $('#container').css('margin-left'));
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#drop_ul').css('width', $('#container').width());
    $('#drop_ul').css('left', $('#container').css('margin-left'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the logic in to its own function which you can then call under both events. Try this:

```
function updateUI() {
    $('#drop_ul').css({
        'width': $('#container').width(),
        'left': $('#container').css('margin-left')
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    updateUI(); // on load
    $(window).on('resize', updateUI); // on window resize
});
```

Note that I unified the `css()` calls, and used the preferred `on` instead of `bind`.

Also, if the site is responsive is would be best to use CSS media queries for this.